# XML Schema Validation failing for derived type

Tags: xml, validation, schema

I would like to know whats the type of an XSD attribute defined as XSD simpleType and below schema is failing validation because of that. please take a loot at this, schema validator tools are throwing error at the "*" demarcated region saying the base attributes type is not derived correctly..not sure if this is even correct structure to define...I have no business model aroud this , I am just trying to play with different options of restrictions and extensions here..

```
    <xsd:complexType name="comptype_simplecontent">
      <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="AAA">
            <xsd:attribute name="aaa_attr" *type="xsd:anySimpleType"*></xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
   </xsd:complexType>

   <xsd:complexType name="AAA" block="extension"> 
    <xsd:simpleContent> 
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:attribute name="aaa_attr">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
                        <xsd:minExclusive value="90"></xsd:minExclusive>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent> 
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

AAA defines a complex type with integer content and a decimal attribute; an example might be

```
<X aaa_attr="93.7">5</X>
```

You define comptype_simplecontent as a restriction of this, which means the elements it allows must be a subset of those that AAA allows. But in your restriction, instead of narrowing the range of values allowed in the attribute, you say that it can take any value at all (anySimpleType). That's not allowed; the restricted type can't allow things that its base type disallows.

Comment: the type I provided "anySimpleType" is just place holder, please fill in this to make the schema validated successfully....

Comment: Because the attribute in the base type uses an anonymous type, I don't think it is possible to restrict it in the restricted type.

Comment: is base="xsd:decimal" not the type of the base attribute "aaa_attr"?

Comment: No, the type of the attribute aaa_attr is an anonymous type derived by restriction from xs:decimal

Comment: I think this might be the reason "2.3.1  {base type definition} must not be the ·ur-type definition".. thanks for your response....